# Changing dot to comma with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to use openpyxl to work with an excel file.
Why doesnt the dot change into a comma?

I added this minimal reproducible Example:

my ExcelFile:

```
111.11
111.12
```

My Code:

```
import openpyxl

def someFunction():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active
    for cell in ws['A']:
        cell.number_format = 'Comma'
        print(cell.number_format)
        print(cell.value)
    wb.save('test.xlsx')

someFunction()
```

Note: I tried different `number_format` values, like `#,##0` and it didnt work either

Expected Output:

```
Comma
111,11
Comma
111,12
```

Actual Output:

```
Comma
111.11
Comma
111.12
```

Comment: Changing number format does not change the value in a cell, only the way its is displayed in Excel. If I have a cell with value 1234567 and use a number format to display it in excel as 01/01/01 the cell value is still 1234567 and that's what Openpyxl will show it as .

Comment: The symbol used for decimals is set globally for Excel in the locale settings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer for you but I have been troubleshooting this for some time and have some takeaways that may help.

You are definitely targeting and affecting the excel sheet.

If you input the desired output 111,111 and then ask what format that cell is you'll find it doesn't say Comma but instead #,##0 - Using this format instead of 'Comma' you can take a value of 111111 and convert it to 111,111... However, you cannot take the value of 111.111 and convert to 111,111 with this format. It will just change to 111 and hide the remaining 3 digits. No idea why it behaves this way.

When using your method and checking the resulting excel file it comes out as a text error and the actual cell contains a date. Something strange is happening here.

- I tried a lot of steps including running outside a function, first formatting the cells to number before changing to comma, targetting individual cells and so on to no avail. Also it seems the comma format always spews an error, so perhaps it's just not supported?